# Using hardware Encryption instead of SSL

Tags: hardware, encryption, ssl, openssl

I am using Freescale iMX6 security processor's CAAM for encryption and decryption of data. But how do I make my system use the hardware encryption instead of software? Do I have to make changes to openssl.cnf?
Where exactly is the code/data that SSL uses to provide encryption etc.?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks! :)

Comment: OpenSSL hardware acceleration code is configured at compile time and enabled runtime if available. This is at least how it works for AES-NI instructions. What does `/proc/crypto` look like on your platform? And what have you found yourself? Googling for CAAM with OpenSSL shows recent changes enabling support for it via the [cryptodev](https://github.com/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux) project (which appears not to be included in Ubuntu repositories). Have you tried compiling the cryptodev project and use it as an OpenSSL engine? (e.g. `openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc -engine cryptodev`)

Comment: I tried using the iMX6 SDK for this but have not run the same directly on the iMX6 machine yet. I will try using cryptodev project as you suggested but as far as I understand cryptodev is software encryption whereas CAAM uses hardware encryption.